# Sikuli - Loop Failing

Tags: loops, sikuli

Good Afternoon, my loop is running correctly for about 4-5 loops. After that, I get the following error.

[image]

It seems that in the loop number 5 it is not taking into account lines 40 and 41 and I don't know why. Here is my code:

My code is the following:

```
def loopAngulo(i):
    j=85.5
    while j <= 90:
        doubleClick("1509640412186.png")
        wait(1)
        type("K")
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(1)
        type("L")
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(1)
        type (str(i))
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(1)
        type (str(2))
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(2)
        type (str(3.27))
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(1)
        type (str(j))
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(1)
        type (str(1))
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(2)
        type ("D")
        type(Key.ENTER)
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(2)
        type (str(50))
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(2.2)
        type (str(2))
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(2.2)
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(2.5)
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(2.4)
        type(Key.LEFT)
        wait(3)
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(3)
        doubleClick("1509667530944.png")
        wait(3)
        type (str(i))
        wait(1.2)
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(1.2)
        type (str(j))
        wait(1.5)
        type(Key.ENTER)
        wait(1.6)
        type(Key.ENTER)
        j+=1.5

i=1.36
while i <= 1.48:
    loopAngulo(i)
    i+=0.12
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is not recommended that errors or code example be posted as links. This is because links can expire or be used for malicious purposes. Please use the pre-formatted text block to post the error, as you did with you example code.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to guess what you might want to achieve, the error you are seeing means that a certain pattern (in the image which name is provided with the error) was not found on the screen. That can happen due to a variety of reasons, e.g. insufficient wait, incorrect/unexpected flow, an so on...

The general approach is to:

1. Split the code into smaller blocks with clear purpose so it is easy to follow and inspect
2. Debug

Another general rule is to verify that what's displayed on the screen is what you expect. Top do that you have to try to define some "hooks" that you can rely on to maintain correct flow.